# Python_ how to change my lines of result?

Tags: python

```
def change_currency(sentence, rate):
    lines = sentence.splitlines()

    words = []
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        words.append(lines[i].split())
    true_wds = sum(words,[])
    for j in range(len(true_wds)):
        if j%4 ==3:
            true_wds[j] = 'YEN'
        elif j%4 ==2:
            true_wds[j] = str(float(true_wds[j])*rate)
        else:
            pass
    ans = ' '.join(true_wds)
    return ans

menu = """Pineapple : 1.5 USD
Biscit : 1 USD
Cupcake : 12 USD
"""

usd = 1000.0 # 1usd = 1000.0yen
result = change_currency(menu, usd)
print(result)
```

In this situation, my result of code is

```
Pineapple : 1500.0 YEN Biscit : 1000.0 YEN Cupcake : 12000.0 YEN
```

But, I want to change my result like this

```
Pineapple : 1500.0 YEN
Biscit : 1000.0 YEN
Cupcake : 12000.0 YEN
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Use `'\n'.join()` intead of `' '.join()` Why is this a hard problem?

Comment: @Barmar, that does not work. Because it adds a new line character after characters like ':' etc.

Comment: Snarkiness is most embarrassing when it follows a wrong answer; the problem occurs due to the `true_wds = sum(words,[])` bit - by flattening the list, you use information you want to use later. Since you already assume a lot, the solution @PCM provided probably meets your need, otherwise you would do well to process the lines in the chunks you already had in `words`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making things complicated by flattening the list, because you're appending each word separately to `true_wds`.

Process each line at once, putting the result in a single element of `true_wds`. Then join that with newline instead of space.

```
def change_currency(sentence, rate):
    lines = sentence.splitlines()

    words = [line.split() for line in lines]
    true_wds = []
    for line in sentence.splitlines():
        item, colon, price, currency = line.split()
        true_wds.append(f"{item} : {float(price) * rate} YEN")
    ans = '\n'.join(true_wds)
    return ans

menu = """Pineapple : 1.5 USD
Biscit : 1 USD
Cupcake : 12 USD
"""

usd = 1000.0 # 1usd = 1000.0yen
result = change_currency(menu, usd)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple. Just add a new line character after "Yen" -

```
true_wds[j] = 'YEN\n'
```

Output:

```
 Pineapple : 1500.0 YEN
 Biscit : 1000.0 YEN
 Cupcake : 12000.0 YEN
```